# ORA-01855: AM/A.M. or PM/P.M. required

Tags: oracle, date, oracle10g, nls-lang

I get the error: `ORA-01855: AM/A.M. or PM/P.M. required`

when I try to execute following query.

```
  INSERT INTO TBL(ID,START_DATE) 
    values (123, TO_DATE ('3/13/2012 9:22:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM'))
```

Where my `START_DATE` column is of type "Date".

I have executed following query and it gave no errors, still not success yet in above issue:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM";
```

Comment: When asking a question if you highlight your code and press the `{}` button at the top of your edit window you code will be formatted so that it's easier to read. In answer to your question you have some seconds in the `to_date` but they're not included in the format mask.

Comment: Ben, I dont want SS to be saved. I want to save only till minutes and then AM/PM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your format mask must match the format of the string you are converting.  So you would either want to add `SS` to the format mask or remove the seconds from the string

```
INSERT INTO TBL(ID,START_DATE) 
  values (123, TO_DATE ('3/13/2012 9:22:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'))
```

or

```
INSERT INTO TBL(ID,START_DATE) 
  values (123, TO_DATE ('3/13/2012 9:22 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'))
```

If you want to accept a string that contains seconds but you don't want to store the seconds in the database (in which case Oracle will always store 0 for the seconds), you can use the `TRUNC` function

```
INSERT INTO TBL(ID,START_DATE) 
  values (123, TRUNC( TO_DATE ('3/13/2012 9:22:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'), 'MI') )
```

Comment: How do i remove it from front-end. I am getting that string as it is from front-end. Is there a way I can change/allow only that string to come. In frontend, it is datetime format.

Comment: @RMN- If you always want the number of seconds to be stored as 0, I updated my answer to include an option of truncating the `DATE` to the minute.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error when running the form builder,
It was fixed by changing the Filed DataType from TIME to CHAR.