# Import date time into Oracle DB using SQL Developer format- "6/26/2018 12:41:00 PM"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, datetime-format

I am trying to import data from CSV file in to Oracle Table.

One of the column is DATETIME,
with an example value- "**6/26/2018  12:41:00 PM**"
(With 2 spaces between date and time)

In Data Import Wizard --> Column Definition --> Data Type

I select "Data Type" as Timestamp.

What should select in the below fields-
Size/Precision- ??   (I tried different sizes like 15, 23, 25,50 )
Format- ??    (I tried various formats- MM/DD/YYYY HH:Mi:SS AM, MM/DD/YYYY HH:Mi:SS)

Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the column in your Oracle table of type `TIMESTAMP`, or `DATE`?

Comment: If it's coming from a CSV, it is text. I believe you can use `TO_DATE(string, format)` to tell Oracle what your string means.

Comment: Basically, I want to upload the columns in timestamp format (from Text DATETIME column).
If not, I can load the column as varchar2 and then probably use this- TO_DATE(string, format) or TO_DATE (SUBSRT("DATETIME, 1, 10), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
but the question remains unresolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my .csv file with the date value as **"6/26/2018 12:41:00 PM"**
select the **DATE** (No timestamp) and used format- **MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI** and it worked for me probably I have all 00 values in my time (SS).

Answer (score 1):

```
Try below format in database and also in excel

Import DB: while loading in table MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM in sql developer using import.

CSV file : Also format the csv file date field with format using custom  m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM
```

Comment: MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM, already tried this, it won't work.
m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM - This isn't working either.

Comment: It worked for me ... I changed format in csv file for timestamp field as m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM and then use the file with import wizard in sql developer. While loading in table use format as MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM it will load successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure it's stored as a date and not as a VARCHAR2.

Then put in a valid NLS_DATE_FORMAT, so we know how to properly insert the record. For your sample, this will do: MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM

[image]

We validate the format, so you can see there's no warning next to the list of dates we are previewing below.

[One might consider this question a duplicate of sorts...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664231/ora-01855-am-a-m-or-pm-p-m-required)

But you're not dealing with the RAW INSERT statement, our GUI is, and this is how you tell us that same information.

Comment: For my .csv file with the date values as **"6/26/2018 12:41:00 PM"**
The **DATE** format I used **MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI** and it worked for me probably I have all 00 values in my time (SS).